# A result that follows from Stokes' theorem-- Important?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, soft-question, vector-fields

From Stokes theorem, it is easy to prove the folowing proposition:

$\int\int_\vec{S}\vec{F}d\vec{S}=0$ if $\vec{F}=curl$ $\vec{G}$ for vector fields $\vec{F}$ and $\vec{G}$ and a closed parametrized surface $\vec{S}$.

Are there any important results that can be derived from this proposition?

Answer (score 1):

One application that immediately springs to mind is classical electrodynamics. The magnetic field $B$ can be described as the curl of the magnetic vector potential $A$.

So, for instance,  this application of Stokes' theorem tells you that the net flux of a magnetic field through a surface is always zero: There are no magnetic monopoles. In physics, this is called Gauss's law for magnetism. The differential form (obtained by integrating by parts over arbitrary surfaces) is perhaps more familiar:
$$\operatorname{div} B = 0$$

Comment: If magnetic monopoles are mathematically impossible, then why does this page exist: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce No one said that magnetic monopoles are mathematically impossible. What was said is that Gauss's law of magnetism is mathematically equivalent to the statement that magnetic monopoles do not exist. So discovering that magnetic monopoles exist afterall would equivalent to discovering that Gauss's law of magnetism isn't always true. The page you referenced describes how Gauss's law would need to be revised if monopoles ever happen to be discovered.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't actually read the page that I posted.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't know the divergence of the curl of any vector field is identically zero, then your proposition plus the Divergence Theorem would show you that this must be the case:

$$\iint_{S}\nabla\times\vec{G}\cdot d\vec{S}=0\implies \iiint_{V}\left(\nabla\cdot\nabla\times\vec{G}\right)dV=0\\
\implies \nabla\cdot\nabla\times\vec{G}=0.$$